# diffuse map bake shows weird helper edge?

Tags: uv, edges, baking, interpolation

So I have an image texture.
[image: my texture]

And I have a (mesh) plane.
And I added a material, the above image texture.
And I assigned the material to the plane.
I made second uv map, and mapped the plane to the first row of windows.
In the original uv map I did the same thing.
Then I bake a diffuse map to the same size image.
[image: result]

At first glance it looks fine. However, if I change white to say blue in an editor, I get this weird line from top left to bottom right.
[image: zoomed in on weird line]

It's like my plane has been divided in two triangles, and the edge is now being baked as well? I tried many things and can't figure out why this happens. When I subdivide the face into smaller pieces, the 'specs' location do change. How do I get wrid of these specs/artifacts?
(PS total blender newb)

[image: shading setup]